# Most powerful SBC for €120/$130?

Tags: raspberry-pi, sbc

I was wondering what is the most powerful SBC for around €100/120. I was thinking about the [Orange Pi 5](http://www.orangepi.org/) more than the [Raspberry Pi 5](https://www.raspberrypi.com/) and even spending something more for a [Nvidia Jetson Nano](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/autonomous-machines/embedded-systems/jetson-nano/education-projects/).

But I don't  know if there are other options/brands that I don't know about.

Comment: Hi Dario! What are you planning on using the SBC for? Different SBC are better/more powerful for different things, so it helps to know what you’re going for.

Comment: android automotive integration

Comment: What part of Android Auto? Like acting as an upgrade for an existing car? If so, drop in products for that already exist.